# "Could you...?" vs. "Were you able to...?"

Tags: modal-verbs, questions, word-difference

I understand the difference in use between 'could' and 'was/were able to' to refer to a specific achievement.

> I was able to attend the meeting yesterday.

He actually attended the meeting.

> I could attend the meeting yesterday.

He had the possibility to attend, but we don't know whether he did or he didn't.

---

Now, my question is as follows: do the same rules apply when we ask a question?

> Were you able to attend the meeting yesterday?

Am I asking whether he attended or not?

> Could you attend the meeting yesterday?

Am I asking the exact same thing as in the sentence above? Or am I simply asking whether he had the possibility to go, whether the possibility existed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's really, really simple. Look at the two sentences. 1) I could run much faster when I was younger. 2) I was able to run much faster when I was younger. There's no difference in meaning between these two sentences. But when you use present perfect tense, you need to use a form of 'be able to,'because there's no form of 'can' or 'could' which you can use. For example:1) He has been able to swim since he was two years old (there's no way to use can or could in this sentence and keep the same meaning) 2) I like being to choose my own working hours(after like we need a verb with -ing, so we need to use be able to-there's no way to use can or could)

Answer (score -2):

> Were you able to attend the meeting yesterday?

Is used as the standard question.

> Could you...

Tends to be used for things that are going to happen in the future, for example

> Could you attend the meeting next week?

However I don't believe there are any strict rules governing what combinations of "could" or "was/were able to" you are allowed to use.