# "I suspect not" or "I don't suspect", when to use which?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In an ELL post ([The difference of a sentence with and without the phrase "in use"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238976/109190)) I said

> I suspect "in use" does not mean "being used" in you example.

If I rewrite the sentence above as the following

> I don't suspect "in use" means "being used" in you example

Is the meaning affected? Which one is more idiomatic? When to use which?

Comment: It would be clearer if rewritten as: **I suspect that (the phrase) **in use** in your example does not mean **being used**. Or **I suspect that in your example, the phrase **in use** does not mean **being used**. In practice, your second sentence is less likely than the first.

Comment: Are you confusing "suspect" and "expect"?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I guess I am not. Oxford: *have an idea or impression of the existence, presence, or truth of (something) without certain proof.
"if you suspect a gas leak, do not turn on an electric light"*

Comment: _Suspect_ is not a verb that's subject to Neg-Raising. So they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @JohnLawler Did you mean "I don't suspect" and "I don't think" are not exchangeable in this case, right?

Comment: No, I meant _I don't suspect S_ and _I suspect that not S_ don't mean the same thing. With _think_, it's different: _I don't think S_ means the same as _I think not S_, because _think_ is a Neg-raising verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.