# "Were you able to" and "are you able to", when to use which?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am aware that "be able to" means "If you are able to do something, you have enough freedom, power, time, or money to do it".

An ELL post(["Could you...?" vs. "Were you able to...?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/115683/109190)) gives an example

> Were you able to attend the meeting yesterday?

I cannot understand in what kind of context a guy would say that, could someone make up a scenario?

Comment: This question is basically saying "I know you *wanted* to go, but were you actually able to?" It presumes the intention, and focuses only on the practicalities.

Answer (score 1):

> > Were you able to attend the meeting yesterday?
>
> I cannot understand in what kind of context a guy would say that, could someone make up a scenario?

**X** misses the meeting. He needs notes. He asks his friend **Y** "were you able to attend the meeting yesterday?".

Comment: I think you need to clarify that this is really asking "Did you attend the meeting yesterday?" Strictly from the definition cited by the OP, the question "Were you able to attend?" seems to be asking whether **Y** was _capable_ of attending yesterday, without actually asking if they did or not.